# Как исправить ошибку? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Tags: javascript

Не понимаю в чем ошибка заключается, вроде как все переменные считаываются в html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте на 41 линии `localStorage.getItem('cart').length` на `dishrow.products.length`.
Возвращает не размер массива, а длину строки json'a

Comment: Исправил спасибо! только исправил на dishrow.products.length тк у меня массив в массиве products если интересна подработка напиши в телегу в шапке моего профиля есть